# Make operations on variable

Tags: bash

`a = 10`

How to make this without making a `expr` command ?

--> `b = $a - 20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(( ))`

Like `b=$(($a-20))`

You welcome

Comment: What are we looking at, and what should a reader do with it and why?

Comment: We're looking "to make this without making a `expr` command "

And for doing "--> `b = $a - 20`" a reader should do "Like `b=$(($a-20))`" because it's the way "to make this without making a `expr` command "